# AspectJ Aspect under JBoss AS 7 throws Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName

Tags: jboss7.x, aspectj, spring-aop

I have a set of WARs that worked without problems on JBoss 6.1.0.Final that use AspectJ 1.6.12 and Spring 3.1.2.RELEASE, built with Maven.  We would like to move to JBoss AS 7 in the near future, so I compiled JBoss 7.1.3.Final from source.

I decided to repackage the application as an EAR file after I had problems with individual WAR files, and so all of our code would be in one, redistributable, deployable unit.

I am having trouble getting our profiling aspect working.  It is an extremely simple aspect contained in a JAR in our EAR/lib directory, that times any method annotated with the @Timed annotation:

```
package com.mycompany.toplayer.perf;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
@Aspect
public class MethodTimerAdvice {
    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Around(value="execution(@com.mycompany.toplayer.perf.Timed * *(..))")
    public Object timeMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable
    {
        String methodName = pjp.getSignature().toShortString();
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Object ret = pjp.proceed();

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long total = end - start;

        long used_mem = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()
                - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
        long mem_gb = used_mem / (1024 * 1024);     

        log.trace("{} | {} | {}M | {} | {} | {}", 
                new Object[] {start, total, 
                        mem_gb, 
                        Thread.currentThread().getId(), 
                        Thread.currentThread().getName(),   
                        methodName}
        );

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Note that the annotation is in the same package.
Here is the relevant Spring configuration file for the aspect, again it is very simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany" />
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy></aop:aspectj-autoproxy>

</beans>
```

There are three WAR files included in the EAR, but right now only one of them is using this aspect, gdm-updater.WAR.  When I attempt to start the server, I get errors like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: Timed [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:301) [aspectjtools.jar:]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:207) [spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getFallbackPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:358) [spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getShadowMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:409) [spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.matches(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:272) [spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:226) [spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:264) [spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:296) [spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:117) [spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:87) [spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:68) [spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:359) [spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322) [spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407) [spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.postProcessObjectFromFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1598) [spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:162) [spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 28 more
```

I also tried including AspectJ as a module, and here is the jboss-deployment-structure.xml file included with the EAR.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
  <deployment>
    <exclusions>
      <module name="org.hibernate" slot="main"/>
    </exclusions>
  </deployment>
  <sub-deployment name="gdm-updater-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.war"> 
      <exclusions>
          <module name="org.hibernate" slot="main"/>
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
          <module name="org.aspectj.tools" slot="main" />
          <module name="org.aspectj.weaver" slot="main" />
        </dependencies>
  </sub-deployment>   
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I even tried using the Maven AspectJ compiler plugin in gdm-updater.war to do compile-time weaving in gdm-updater.war's pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
        <source>${compiler.version}</source>
        <target>${compiler.version}</target>
        <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
        <complianceLevel>${compiler.version}</complianceLevel>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <verbose>false</verbose>
        <aspectLibraries>
            <aspectLibrary>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            </aspectLibrary>
        </aspectLibraries>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

I can't get anything working.
I searched the web for answers and found a couple of links, but none seem to be relevant:

[Has anyone run AspectJ with JBoss AS 7.1.1 final?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698631/has-anyone-run-aspectj-with-jboss-as-7-1-1-final) - not relevant since I'm not using load-time weaving

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-3681 - not relevant since I'm not using load-time weaving or AspectJ as a Java agent

I've considered load-time weaving, but the aspect in question will soon be expanded to include some features present in the rest of that "common" jar file, and I can't break that out to the boot classpath.  It would mean that every time we have a new aspect, we have to reconfigure the server.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

For me, for the most part this "just works". I have an [example](https://github.com/eis/jboss-7.2-osgi-blueprint-gemini-poc/tree/master/spring-mvc-aop-datasource) [projects](https://github.com/eis/jboss-7.2-osgi-blueprint-gemini-poc/tree/master/spring-mvc-aop) where I've been testing simple aspects without load-time-weaving working with JBoss AS7.

The part that doesn't work for me is that if I have specified an object like this:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jboss/datasources/ExampleDS"/>
```

this has problems, because JBoss internal modules are loaded with ModuleClassLoader, that has visibility only to that specific module. However Aspect-J tries to check my aspects on that and fails, because that specific classloader doesn't have my aspect class loaded. It's the same thing as [explained here](http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-113581.html).

Workaround is to have a dependency on jdbc internals in module.xml / jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
<deployment>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters"/>
  </dependencies>
</deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

If you use a debugger you can hook up on the exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException and check which classloader is it using and what class it is trying to load from the call stack. That's what I did.

Another workaround I found was to do a JNDI lookup directly in the code and not on Spring context. That works as well.

I've also opened [AS7-6305 / WFLY-826](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-826) on this issue.

Update: issue has been rejected on the JBoss side. They claim it's a problem on AspectJ. I've opened also a [bug there](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=397829), for which there has been no comments.

Comment: I see the issue was rejected.  Thanks for trying at least!

Comment: @Brad no problem. I updated the answer to also refer to aspect-j bug report.

Answer (score 2):

We recently experienced a similar issue when upgrading from JBoss EAP 6.4.8 to 6.4.9.

It would appear that the DataSource implementation for our JNDI DataSources was changed from `org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource` to `org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource`.

We added the following deployment dependency to our application's `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file which has resolved the issue for us.

```
<module name="org.jboss.as.connector" slot="main"/>
```

This module contains the `WildFlyDataSource` implementation. Like other people in this thread we previously already had the `org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters` dependency. It looks like the `org.jboss.as.connector` module can replace this.

As was discussed in [@eis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14253890/304617) the issue was related to JNDI datasources, AspectJ, Spring and classloading. The only way I was able to catch this was to run up JBoss locally and put a breakpoint on IllegalArgumentException.

An alternate fix was to proxy your DataSources using the `proxy-interface` in your Spring configuration - e.g.

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="some_jndi_name" proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I found at least a partial solution here...

http://pushpendrasinghbaghel.blogspot.com/2013/01/spring-aop-and-jbossas-7.html

The problem seems to occur anytime that something needs to be advised that is loaded by the classloader that loads the core JBoss modules...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I have solved it by downgrading version of spring-aop library to 3.0.7.RELEASE. Of course it is just temporary solution and I am waiting for true reason of this issue.